# How to Use AdAccount in RestFB (with a working example)?

Tags: restfb

I am using restfb for making API calls and and fetch reports. The API calls are successful, but i don't know how to use `AdAccount`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Tried searching on google but no solution

Comment: What do you try to do. Creating an AdAccount, reading it? can you specify a bit more what's going on?